# Not getting good reflection readings on lidar(VLP-16)

Tags: lidar

I mounted VLP-16 on the roof of my car while driving, I was expecting the lidar can detect the lanes on the ground since the white lines should have higher reflectivity.

But in fact I cannot see any patterns on the ground. [screenshot of rviz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvjEM.png)
The image was my rviz screenshot, I can get some higher intensity value on vertical objects, but cannot detect the lanes on the ground.

Is this normal? Do I need to calibrate my lidar for lane detection?

Comment: General hardware issues with a sensor that do not involve programming are unfortunately off topic for Stack Overflow.  I'm not sure where you can get help with this issue.  Perhaps the manufacturer has a forum?

Comment: This seems like a better fit for one of the other sites. Perhaps: https://robotics.stackexchange.com/.